# ClearPath: crowd collision avoidance

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, collision-detection, path-finding

I am working to implement this algorithm:

http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/CA/ClearPath.pdf

[image]

I do not understand why the authors moved the cone's apex from `Vb` to `(Va + VB)/2`.
I don't understand what is thee significance or intuition behind it.

Comment: From the paper: Recently, Van den Berg et al. [BLM08, BPS08] presented an extension called RVO. The resulting velocity computation algorithm guarantees oscillation free behavior for two
agents. An RVO is formulated by moving the apex of the VO cone from vB to (vA+vB)/2.
.

Comment: I guess I need to delve in to the other paper.  :)

Answer (score 0):

From the paper: Recently, Van den Berg et al. [BLM08, BPS08] presented an extension called RVO. The resulting velocity computation algorithm guarantees oscillation free behavior for two agents. An RVO is formulated by moving the apex of the VO cone from vB to (vA+vB)/2.